# shell script storing run time with python

Tags: python, time

I am trying to store the run time of a python program using this

```
{ time python experiments.py --model iwae --k $k ; } 2> time$k.txt
```

when I do this in a shell script, I get

```
40.35user 3.12system 0:43.00elapsed 101%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 850788maxresident)k
0inputs+30344outputs (0major+159448minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

when I only execute one line , I get

```
real    0m16.367s
user    0m15.420s
sys 0m1.436s
```

which is what I want.

Can someone help me with logging run time of python script and storing the runtime in a text file please?

script

```
# ! /bin/sh

for k in 3 5 10; do

echo $k

sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64

{ time python experiments.py --model iwae --k $k ; } 2> time$k.txt

done
```

Comment: It looks like the script is executing the external `/usr/bin/time` instead of your interactive shell's `time` built-in. You'll need to provide more details of your script and how you're running it to be sure.

Comment: Hi thanks, it looks something like this #! /bin/sh
for k in 3 5 10; do
echo $k
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
{ time python experiments.py --model iwae --k $k ; } 2> time$k.txt
done

Answer (score 3):

`time` is many things. There's the external [`/usr/bin/time` GNU program](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/). There's the [bash keyword `time`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#index-time).

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

When you run `time …` in an interactive shell, you'd be typically using bash, and so the `time` keyword takes effect.

When you run `time …` in a script using `/bin/sh`, the shell used (`dash`)
 doesn't have `time` as a keyword, and the external `time` command is called.

To get the output you want, call the external [`time`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/time.1.html) command with the `-p` option:

```
-p, --portability
      Use the following format string, for conformance with POSIX
      standard 1003.2:
                real %e
                user %U
                sys %S
```

The external command is also more friendly. Since it isn't a keyword, you don't need to do the wrap-in-`{ … }`-for-redirection trick to get the output in a file. There's an option for that:

```
-o FILE, --output=FILE
      Write the resource use statistics to FILE instead of to the
      standard error stream.  By default, this overwrites the file,
      destroying the file's previous contents.  This option is useful
      for collecting information on interactive programs and programs
      that produce output on the standard error stream.
```

The output is also far more customizable, making it easier for processing later on. With bash's `time`, the options provided in `TIMEFORMAT` are very limited.